# Jhipster doesn't translate at the beginning

Tags: jhipster

I created a new page with two entities:

- productDelivered
- category

No matter what language I choose, I can’t get it translated. For example, heading for category name is:

```
<th><span data-translate="barfitterApp.category.name">Name</span></th>
```

And I see only: barfitterApp.category.name
[image]

But when I go to Entities->Category, then Entities->Product Delivereds [which are ok and translated] and then back to a new page with two entities, now they are translated.
[image]

How can I load translations during my first visit on new page?

Comment: Please provide JHipster version. Also have you seen any error in browser's console? It looks like a promise that is not resolved before netering your state, how did you define the `resolve` property of your state?

Answer (score 2):

OK, solved.
It was missing

```
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('authorization');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('category');
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('productDelivered');
```